# How can I make `time` use the same format when there is stdin present?

Tags: time

On OSX I'd like these to be the same (preferably the first format). How do I do it without post-processing?

```
$ time echo foo
foo

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ echo | time echo foo
foo
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-p` option: "The output is formatted as specified by IEEE Std 1003.2-1992 ('POSIX.2')." This isn't perfect (there seems to be some tab/space weirdness going on), but the times themselves will be formatted the same:

```
$ time -p echo foo
foo
real 0.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00

$ echo | time -p echo foo
foo
real         0.00
user         0.00
sys          0.00
```